# Scrapy & Selenium - Load next pages

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the following website: https://sabobic.blogabet.com

My crawler already crawls the content I need. But after clicking on the "See older"-Button I do not know how to start my method "crawltips" again.

This is my current code:

```
class AlltipsSpider(Spider):
    name = 'alltips'
    allowed_domains = ['blogabet.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
        # Place all user urls here
        url = "https://sabobic.blogabet.com"
        self.driver.get(url)
        yield scrapy.http.Request (url, callback=self.crawltips)


    def crawltips(self, response):
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        allposts = sel.xpath('//*[@class="block media _feedPick feed-pick"]')

        for post in allposts:
            username = post.xpath('.//div[@class="col-sm-7 col-lg-6 no-padding"]/a/@title').extract()
            publish_date = post.xpath('.//*[@class="bet-age text-muted"]/text()').extract()

            yield{'Username': username,
                'Publish date': publish_date
                }

        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_id('last_item').click()
            sleep(5)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            self.logger.info('No more tipps')
        yield Request(url, callback=self.crawltips)
```

I think something is wrong with the yield function because I dont have a new url...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
yield scrapy.Request(self.driver.current_url,callback=self.crawltips)
```